# Deserialize Boolean from Soap using Servicestack

Tags: soap, servicestack

I am issuing a soap request from SSRS to servicestack and no matter what I try, I can't get Servicestack to recognize anything as a boolean value and deserialize it.

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/Stuff")]
public class GetStuff : IReturn<GetStuffResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Is Enabled",
        DataType = "bool",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

The incoming soap request looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetStuff xmlns="http://www.myCompany.com/types">
      <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
    </GetTradesGroupedByClient>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried to make the soap request send "0" and "1" for true/false, and true with a capital "T", but Servicestack always deserializes it as 'null'.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit 1**

Update on further strangeness.  I replaced the bool with int in the hopes that would be less of a hassle, however this also didn't deserialize.  So I added some fields to the request to see if all deserialization would fail:

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/Stuff")]
public class GetStuff : IReturn<GetStuffResponse>
{
    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Summary Date",
        DataType = "DateTime",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public DateTime? SummaryDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Summary End Date",
        DataType = "DateTime",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public DateTime? SummaryEndDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Symbol",
        DataType = "string",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Email",
        DataType = "string",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ApiMember(Name = "Is Enabled",
        DataType = "int",
        IsRequired = false)]
    public int? IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the soap being sent to serviceStack:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetStuff xmlns="http://www.myCompany.com/types">
      <SummaryDate>2018-04-26</SummaryDate>
      <SummaryEndDate>2018-04-26</SummaryEndDate>
      <Symbol>TOU</Symbol>
      <Email>Guy.Smiley@myCompany.net</Email>
      <IsEnabled>1</IsEnabled>
    </GetStuff>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now here is where it gets weird, the two dates and the 'symbol' field deserialize correctly.  The 'Email' field and the 'IsEnabled' fields fail and are null.  Is there some way to trace the Deserializer in Serivcestack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't use it's own XML Serializer, it uses .NET's WCF `Message` class and .NET's Xml DataContract Serializer to serialize/deserialize SOAP requests.

WCF's SOAP is very strict/fragile, so you'll need to capture exactly what's sent to know what's the right SOAP/XML to send. Easiest way to do that is to use the [Soap12ServiceClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#httpwebrequest-service-clients) to send your Request DTO and a packet sniffer like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the raw HTTP Request body that's sent, e.g:

```
var client = new Soap12ServiceClient(baseUrl);

var request = new GetStuff {
    SummaryDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-04-26"),
    SummaryEndDate = DateTime.Parse("2018-04-26"),
    Symbol = "TOU",
    Email = "Guy.Smiley@myCompany.net",
    IsEnabled = true,
};

var response = client.Send(request);
```

Which sends the SOAP Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">GetStuff</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:5cb1b87c-82ae-422b-9b6a-3044eeb90fe7</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://test.servicestack.net/Soap12</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetStuff xmlns="http://schemas.servicestack.net/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Email>Guy.Smiley@myCompany.net</Email>
         <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
         <SummaryDate>2018-04-26T00:00:00</SummaryDate>
         <SummaryEndDate>2018-04-26T00:00:00</SummaryEndDate>
         <Symbol>TOU</Symbol>
      </GetStuff>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Notice the order of properties is in Alphabetical order which is important in SOAP/XML.

Comment: truer words could not have been spoken: WCF's SOAP is very fragile!!!!  I would never have considered that the alphabetical order of parameters in an xml based document would ever matter!  Thank you very much for this insight.  As a follow up for SSRS users, you can alter the order of the parameters generated by the query in the 'parameters' tab of the 'Dataset properties' dialog.  Order them alphabetically by hand using the up/down arrows.